# Divs and AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I find myself using a lot of divs when programming with AngularJS.  Is this normal, or is there a better way of using Angular directives without divs?  I believe that excessive use of div tags makes the HTML ugly, hard to read, and lacking in semantics.

Comment: what do you mean? you could use `<p>` or `<section>` instead... thats a html semantic problem not an angular one I believe

Comment: what does `<div>` have to do with anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanting your Markup to be more semantic and readable from a programmers point of view and you wish to encapsulate some reusable functionality then Directives will help as something like:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
   return {
  restrict: 'AE',
  replace: 'true',
  template: '<div><h1>My Title</h1><div>Hello World!!</div></div>'
   };
});
```

Can be included in your HTML as:

```
<hello-world><hello-world>
```

But the Rendered HTML will still be the divs, otherwise it maybe of more benefit to try to include more HTML5 semantic tags found here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

Comment: why is using a directive any different than any other place you have markup? Can use any valid tag wherever it is appropriate. Answer makes no sense in context of the question